# Trigger event when a certain element has been removed

Tags: slate.js

I'm building an editor using the excellent [Slate](http://slatejs.org/) editor, but I'm having trouble with a certain task. I've built a drag-and-drop image upload that successfully uploads images (via API, not related to Slate) and inserts them into the editor. However, I want to delete the image from the server if the user deletes it in the editor. Is there a way to trigger functions when a certain `node` type is removed from the `state`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just started looking at slate and was looking into the same issue. My solution is to:

- create a plugin function for image handling `(options) => { /* plugin object */}`
- In this plugin function, in `schema.nodes`, return a wrapper around my main `Image` component that sets an `onDelete` prop from the options parameter.

```js
//ImagePlugin function

export default function ImagePlugin(options) {
  return {
    schema: {
      nodes: {
        image: props => <Image
          {...Object.assign({ onDelete: options.onDelete }, props) } />
      }
    }
  }
```